# How to switch x and y axis around?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Got this plot and it's all correct apart from the fact the data is plotted the wrong way around on the axis - is there an easy way to switch them without going back through all the arrays and changing the values manually? Sorry for the long code, most of it is just defining parameters. Thanks!

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from math import sqrt
%matplotlib inline

r1=0.01 # growth rate B
r2=0.03 # growth rate M
KB = 20 # carrying capacity B
KM = 6000 # carrying capacity M
x=np.arange(0,70) # distance from the coast (100m)
y=np.arange(0,90) # distance from the coast
dx=1 # change in x position
dy=1 # change in y position
dt=0.1 # time step
m=71 # number of x steps
o=91 # number of y steps
n=1001 # time
alpha =  0.000002 # predation rate
beta = 0 # growth rate from predation (assumed to be zero)

B=np.zeros(shape=(m,o,n)) # density of species B at (x,y) at time t
M=np.zeros(shape=(m,o,n)) # density of species B at (x,y) at time t
D=0.035 # diffusivity of B
D2=0.005 # diffusivity of M
Alpha=(D*dt)/(dx*dx)
Beta=(D*dt)/(dy*dy) 
Alpha2=(D2*dt)/(dx*dx)
Beta2 = (D2*dt)/(dy*dy)

M[0,:,0]=0 #initial conditions
M[m-1,:,0]=0
M[:,0,0]=0
M[:,o-1,0]=0
B[0,:,0]=0 #initial conditions
B[m-1,:,0]=0
B[:,0,0]=0
B[:,o-1,0]=0
B[1:26,1:o-1,0]=0.96
B[26:44,1:o-1,0]=4.6
B[44:m-1,1:o-1,0]=0.96
B[1:m-1,1:31,0]=0.96
B[1:m-1,59:o-1,0]=0.96
M[1:26,:,0]=2500
M[26:44,:,0]=1000
M[44:m-1,:,0]=2500
M[:,1:31,0]=2500
M[:,59:o-1,0]=2500
for k in range(0,n-1): # loop for time
    B[0,:,k+1]=B[1,:,k+1] # boundary conditions
    B[m-1,:,k+1]=B[m-2,:,k+1]
    M[0,:,k+1]=0
    M[m-1,:,k+1]=0
    B[:,0,k+1]=B[:,1,k+1]
    B[:,o-1,k+1]=B[:,m-2,k+1]
    M[:,0,k+1]=0
    M[:,o-1,k+1]=0
    for i in range(1,m-1): # loop for x
        for j in range(1,o-1): # loop for y
            Bdxx=(-2*Alpha)*B[i,j,k]+Alpha*B[i+1,j,k]+Alpha*B[i-1,j,k]
            Bdyy=(-2*Beta)*B[i,j,k]+Beta*B[i,j+1,k]+Beta*B[i,j-1,k]
            B[i,j,k+1]=B[i,j,k]+Bdxx+Bdyy+r1*B[i,j,k]*(1-B[i,j,k]/KB)-alpha*M[i,j,k]*B[i,j,k] # numerical solution for B 
            Mdxx=(-2*Alpha2)*M[i,j,k]+Alpha2*M[i+1,j,k]+Alpha2*M[i-1,j,k]
            Mdyy=(-2*Beta2)*M[i,j,k]+Beta2*M[i,j+1,k]+Beta2*M[i,j-1,k]
            M[i,j,k+1]=M[i,j,k]+Mdxx+Mdyy+r2*M[i,j,k]*(1-M[i,j,k]/KM)+beta*M[i,j,k]*B[i,j,k] # numerical solution for M
            if B[i,j,k] < 0:
                B[i,j,k] = 0

plt.pcolormesh(B[:,:,n-1]) 
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('X Position')
plt.ylabel('Y Position')
```

Comment: Perhaps `plt.pcolormesh(B[:,:,n-1].T)`?

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much - I can't believe I didn't think of that lol

Comment: If DavidG's suggestion doesn't work, transpose B with `BT = B.T` then plot with `plt.pcolormesh(BT)`